# Set two Hook states with useEffect in Context Provider

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-context

I'm new to learning React (without backend, with Context API).
In the Context Provider, I'm looking for a way to set two Hook states from the same data.
To make a single axios call (without re-rendering). The Provider takes in App. Are there any solutions?

```
export const Context = React.createContext();

const MoviesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  console.log("Context Affectations");

  const [movies, setMovies] = React.useState(null);
  const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Context useEffect 1");
    const dataGet = externalData;
    setMovies(dataGet);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Context useEffect 2");
    // SKIPPED PART
    const dataGet = externalData;
    setSelectedMovie(dataGet[0]);
    // SKIPPED PART
  });
```

Tried both in the same useEffect, the second is skipped too.

Console:

```
Context Affectations
Context useEffect 1
Pass data
Context useEffect 2
Context Affectations
```

Comment: Is `dataGet` working? Looking at this on the surface, React appears to be behaving as expected, and it's your Axios call that is not working.

Comment: "dataGet" working, "movies" is well updated.
To avoid many calls in this example (and to exclude axios behavior), i'm using a data file.

Comment: Thanks, indeed in using a direct const "externalData" that works, so the problem is from behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you should do a quick read on `useEffect's` dependency array and why is super useful [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-the-useeffect-dependency-array-2913da504c44). What you are trying to solve can be achieved with one useEffect without issues.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Context useEffect 2");
    // SKIPPED PART
    const dataGet = externalData;
    setMovies(dataGet);
    setSelectedMovie(dataGet[0]);
    // SKIPPED PART
  }, []); // <- Important part this empty array means that this will run only at the mount of the component (first time appearing) but you could put inside the variable to watch so every time that changes it fetches again
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this usefull article.

Comment: If this works do you mind approving it and giving an upvote? (it may help somebody else in the future)

Comment: I don't understand why people don't upvote or accept answers.

Comment: Most of them don't know tbh... Everytime I need to ask...

Comment: Upvoted 37min ago in the same time as rep but no increment (edit: only vote from >15 reputations displayed).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single `useEffect` making an axios call when the component mounts (aka. is appearing).

That `useEffect` can call both setters for your two useState's.

Also don't forget to add the [dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) when calling a setter inside `useEffect` otherwise it will loop indefinitely.

It can be empty in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.